# Exception in beginTransaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate in my web application,when I am getting exception while:

```
Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
```

It gives exception once in a while, I am reloading `SessionFactory` while catching the exception and then it runs fine.

It is working when I am reloading the SessionFactory again.

This is my code snippet:

```
 session = HibernateFactory.openSession(0);//Passing 0 uses the existing sessionFactory
        if(session.isConnected() && session.isOpen() && session!=null)
        {
           try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            logger.info("Transaction is begin successfully--Transaction is--"+tx);
            }catch(Exception e){
            logger.info("Could not start the transaction--Transaction is--"+tx);
               session = HibernateFactory.openSession(1);//passing 1 is creating new     //--SessionFactory
               tx = session.beginTransaction();//now this runs fine
               logger.info("Inside catch--Obtained session--"+session+"and transaction--"+tx);
               e.printStackTrace();
               logger.error("e.getCause(): "+e.getCause());
               logger.error("e.getClass(): "+e.getClass());
              // throw new HibernateException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

This is the stackTrace of the exception I am getting.

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
        at com.arosys.hibernateDao.AbstractDao.startOperation(AbstractDao.java:184)
        at com.arosys.hibernateDao.AbstractDao.findAll(AbstractDao.java:150)
        at com.arosys.beansDao.JobHierarchyDao.findAll(JobHierarchyDao.java:20)
        at org.ArosysLogin.server.GWTJobImpl.getJobHierarchy(GWTJobImpl.java:416)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
```

Comment: reloading (I guess recreating) the SessionFactory sounds to harsh. Creating a new Session should be enough.

Comment: Exception trace would help checking what's going wrong 'once a while'.

Comment: I have updated my post..thanks for putting my attention there.Amandeep

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing since there isn't enough information (type and message of the exception):

- Connection fails due to flaky database/network connection
- do you commit your transactions? I'm not sure, but Hibernate might complain if you try to start a transaction twice.

UPDATE based on the call stack.

This seems to be a problem with the database. check out the various results for googling "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure"

This one might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally

Are you sure your connections get closed after usage? I can imagine the database denying access after so many connections are opened. Checking the logs of your database might help as well.

Comment: Long answer: I never know. I find Hibernate Transaction/Session handling terrible confusing and highly configurable. At the beginning of a Hibernate project I write a couple of tests and some reading until this stuff behaves how I like it.
Short answer: I think you can configure it that way. But I don't know how right now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `ValidateConnectionOnBorrow` to `true`
2. and add a validation query for `SQLForValidateConnection`
3. Set `autoReconnect` to true for jdbc URL

either by **Server connection pool** configuration or **connection pool** configuration.

I assume(from the stack trace) that you are using MySQL,Hibernate with either JBoss or  Tomcat.

Let me know in case you face any problem, I faced the same long ago.

Comment: yes I am using tomcat,mysql and hibernate in my application.I have already set autoreconnect to true I am using C3p0 can you please tell me that what is exactly the property name you mentioned above and what they does.

Comment: hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period or hibernate.c3p0.validate. See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=353736&seqNum=4

Comment: @AmandeepSingh One more thing, timeout Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 0
it is the seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire. See: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool

Comment: Thanks Puspendu,as you mentioned that any one of the above properties needed to set.I have already set "hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" property but unfortunately it is not working for me till now..Can you suggest any changes or something that may be missing.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh I regret myself, I was quite occupied for last 2 days.would you mind to share your configuration details?

Comment: ,Here is my configuratuin details connection_provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider

connection.autoReconnect= true
connection.autoReconnectForPools=true
connection.is-connection-validation-required=true
hibernate.c3p0.validate=true
current_session_context_class=thread
cache.use_query_cache=false
cache.use_second_level_cache=false
c3p0.acquire_increment=1
c3p0.idle_test_period=39
c3p0.max_size=100
c3p0.max_statements=0
c3p0.min_size=1
c3p0.timeout=40
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=select 1

Comment: looks like you need to modify as "hibernate.c3p0.xxxxxx" for all entries. Ref: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#hibernate-specific